# Android app does not start (and is invisible!) on device

Tags: android, netbeans

I have a strange problem with my Android app. When I start it from Netbeans, the app gets installed on my device (attached via USB). After that nothing happens. I also can't find the app anywhere on the device!! (no icon, no nothing).
Still I know the app has been installed, because under the android settings, where it says "Manage Applications" (or something) the app is now listed and I can uninstall it.

I've tried the whole procedure with a blank HelloWorld app, which worked fine. Here an icon got created o the device and the app was started correctly by NetBeans.

So I guess there is something wrong with my app causing it not to appear in the phone's launcher?

EDIT:
Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your the content of your Androidmanifest  ?

Comment: I would also recommend posting the content of your Androidmanifest, but could you also briefly describe the contents of your app (types of activities or xml files, etc).

Comment: I've attached the manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add below line in your Main activity in androidmanifest file

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER is necessary to be shown in launcher,  and android.intent.action.MAIN is responsible for being started

Comment: I mentioned that below your mainActivity in your manifest file.